# python basics:how to take the complete input first and get the complete output later?

Tags: python, python-2.7

OK so i just started learning python and i was solving codechef problems
i wrote the following solution for 
[this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP) problem:

```
testcase = input()
remain = []
chef = []
assistant = []
for _ in range(testcase):
    comp,rem = map(int,raw_input().split())
 for _ in range(1,comp+1):
    remain.append(_)
    temp = map(int,raw_input().split())
    remain = [x for x in remain if x not in temp]
  for i in range(len(remain)):
    if i%2==0:
        chef.append(remain[i])
    else:   
        assistant.append(remain[i])
  sarr = [str(a) for a in chef]
  darr = [str(a) for a in assistant]        
  print " ".join(sarr)
  print " ".join(darr)  
  remain[0:] = []
  chef[0:] = []
  assistant[0:] = []
```

now the program is doing what its supposed to do but i want to take all the inputs before getting the output as shown in [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP) problem example

Comment: Instead of dumping your whole code, it is helpful to distill it down to the essentials, especially if you can work with a toy example.

Comment: Also, this is more of a stylistic issue, but I would avoid using `raw_input` in functional constructs like `map` (or, for example, list comprehensions).

Comment: Are you looking for something like what i have shown in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Read all of the inputs into some kind of collection (a list would be the most straight-forward choice), and then get them from that collection for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this and then process the stored input later:

```
comp=[]
rem=[]
indexes = []

for _ in range(testcase):
    rem_t,comp_t = map(int,raw_input().split())
    rem.append(rem_t)
    comp.append(comp_t)

    for _ in range(1,comp[i]+1):
      indexes.append(map(int,raw_input().split()))
```

---

Now for each test case i, you need to define `chef` and `assitant` lists inside the loop and manipulate the input stored in `comp[i], rem[i] and indexes[i]` :

```
for i in range(testcase):
    # define chef and assistant lists.
    # use comp[i], rem[i] and indexes[i].
    # print the the content of chef and assistant array.
```

Comment: i did try to store the output but the thing is if i store all the outputs in a single list outside the loop,i have no way to differentiate the output for a single test case with different number of jobs.

Comment: @virenkanjani, well as per the problem statement you are referring to, each test case has 2 lines, one with values of n and m and the second with m-elements. so for each test case you have n,m and a list.  which is nothing but comp[i], rem[i] and index[i] (index is a list of lists) for test case i. Is it clear enough ?